# Ambiguous error when attempting to filter values using enum

Tags: ios, swift

I have a filter that I am trying to use to compare one value to another. Here is the enum that I am using:

```
enum SomeEnum: String {

    case first  = "Hey"
    case second = "There"
    case third  = "Peace"

static let values = [first, second, third]

func pickOne() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .first:
            return "value 1"
        case .second:
            return "value 2"
        case .third:
            return "value 3"
    }
}
```

Here is where I am attempting to filter and find matching values:

```
array.append(SomeEnum.values.filter({$0.rawValue ==  anotherArray["id"] as! String}))
```

I end up getting an ambiguous error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[SomeEnum]' to expected argument type 'String'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the types of `array`?

Comment: @DejanSkledar Array is of type [String].

Comment: What's your `anotherArray`? You're trying to subscript it like a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that `SomeEnum.values` return type is `[SomeEnum]` and not `String`.

And the `append` function expects the parameter to be `String`, instead it is `[SomeEnum]`.

This is, what you need to change:

1. Change `append` to `appendContentsOf`, since `filter` function returns an array, and not a single value
2. Change the `[SomeEnum]` to `[String]` since you are adding it to a `[String]` array, like this.

This is the fix:

```
array.appendContentsOf(SomeEnum.values.filter({ $0.rawValue == "SomeString" }).map({ $0.PickOne() }))
```

Comment: I edited my code, but if I enter $0.rawValue == "Hey" then it returns "Hey". I'd like to return case .first value of "value 1". Does that make sense? The errors were fixed, tho! :D

Comment: Okay, I edited your answer. It works just fine now. Thanks!! :D